# Google play closed test for 20 testers requirements

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-play, google-play-console, mobile-development

we have develope an android application and i want to published it on google play store. We have around 25 testers .

I need to know that how 20 testers opted in count works ? whether the installation of the app count? on per device and per email id or how? please any one has the information please suggests us...

Comment: also can i get how many of users has opted in for closed test?

Comment: I think only the official support will be able to help you in this manner. Please contact the support via this link and describe the question you have in there: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the email of someone to the List of Testers in the Closed Test section, and they need to download your app from the link you gave them but they need to be logged in in Google Play with the same email you added to the Testers List